# Selenium click() working but submit() isn't

Tags: php, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-testing

In some of my Selinium Webdriver tests, I've noticed that I'm unable to submit a form by calling `submit()` on any of the elements of the form, but I can call `click()` on the submit button just fine. I've created a simple test web page to illustrate the problem. In the example below, when I call `submit()`, I see the submit button. But when I call `click()`, the form is actually submitted and I see 'Submitted'.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php if(isset($_POST["submit"])): ?>
    Submitted
    <?php else: ?>
      <form method="post">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template) Selenium template, and here is how my test looks:

```
@Listeners(ScreenshotListener.class)
public class LoginTest extends SeleniumBase {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        WebDriver driver = getDriver();
        driver.get("http://localhost/test.php");
        WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.id("submit"));
        submit.click(); // works
        // submit.submit(); // doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't submit a button, give an ID to form element e.g. `id="myForm"` and try `WebElement form = driver.findElement(By.id("myForm")); form.submit();`

Comment: @msdesdev Selenium let's you call `submit()` on any element inside of a form, which should cause the form itself to submit, so this should work. But I tried your method anyway, and it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more, I don't work with Selenium ;)

Comment: Works for me with python-bindings

Comment: Which browser are you executing this test in ? When I worked in IE, I had issues executing certain statements that worked in Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: @Sri I've only tested in Firefox and Chrome and it doesn't work on either. I'm running Linux, so I can't test IE.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so, I have a similar issue and I'd like to share a solution that has been serving me well thus far.  On some of the web pages I have to use `.Submit()` and on some I have to use `.Click()` on the button element.  The page that I have to use `.Click()` on, will tell me that username or password I entered is incorrect; eventhough, if I leave out the `.Submit()` portion and click manually, it logs in with the programatically filled in credentials.  So, I had to find its button element by its id and use `.Click()` on it. The second website has a completely opposite behavior and does nothing when `.Click()` is being used on the button.  Instead, `.Submit()` works.

So, to get around this whole mess until I figure it out (and I've bee at it for a while), here's what I've done.  Most of the websites perform submission on the `Enter` key down event, so, that's exactly what I did.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
private void Login(string url, string usernameElement, string username, 
                   string passwordElement, string password)
{
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Id(usernameElement));
    query.SendKeys(username);
    query = driver.FindElement(By.Id(passwordElement));
    query.SendKeys(password);
    query.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);  // simulates Enter key down to submit
}
```

This little change saved me a whole lot of headache.  I've tested it on several other websites and no issues thus far.  I know it's not a complete fix of the library issue, but it's **A** fix.